# Replace NAs for a group of values with a non-NA character in group in R

Tags: r, fill

I'm trying to find a way to Replace NAs for a group of values with a non-NA character by group, if this non-NA character does not always appear in the same place (first row or other). The solutions I found don't work for characters or only fill based on a previous or subsequent value.

Here is an example of data:

```
participant_id <- c("ps1", "ps1", "ps1", "ps1", "ps2", "ps2", "ps3", "ps3", "ps3", "ps3")
test <- c("test1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "test2", NA, NA, "test3", NA)
data.frame(participant_id, test)
```

This is what I would like to end up with:

| participant_id | test |
| --- | --- |
| ps1 | test1 |
| ps1 | test1 |
| ps1 | test1 |
| ps1 | test1 |
| ps2 | test2 |
| ps2 | test2 |
| ps3 | test3 |
| ps3 | test3 |
| ps3 | test3 |
| ps3 | test3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative way using `na.locf` from `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(participant_id) %>% 
  arrange(participant_id, test) %>% 
  mutate(test = zoo::na.locf(test, na.rm=FALSE))
```

```
   participant_id test 
   <chr>          <chr>
 1 ps1            test1
 2 ps1            test1
 3 ps1            test1
 4 ps1            test1
 5 ps2            test2
 6 ps2            test2
 7 ps3            test3
 8 ps3            test3
 9 ps3            test3
10 ps3            test3
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `fill` from `tidyr` after grouping by 'participant_id'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(participant_id) %>%
    fill(test, .direction = "downup") %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   participant_id test 
   <chr>          <chr>
 1 ps1            test1
 2 ps1            test1
 3 ps1            test1
 4 ps1            test1
 5 ps2            test2
 6 ps2            test2
 7 ps3            test3
 8 ps3            test3
 9 ps3            test3
10 ps3            test3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(participant_id, test)
```